Adding attribute to HTML elements to whole code
I'm using Nuxt 2 in my project with Storyblok datasources as translations and e.g. I've:
<span v-text="$t('labels.cartSell')" /> and I need to add something like data-translation="labels.cartSell" to that span. The problem is I've more than 600 $t uses in my code. Is there any possibility to add attribute automatically to every element in my code which contain $t?

if not programmatically
you can use find and replace in an IDE like vs code
and use regex or word match to match exact query.

and if programmatically maybe can use
    var element = document.querySelector("selector"); 
    element.setAttribute("attr", "val"); 

